# Is there any jquery plugin that mimics the amazon.com menu layout

Tags: jquery, css, menu

I am looking to create a web page with a menu layout similar to amazon.com where I could have nested menus and include the small description text below each menu item.

Before I start to create this from scratch, I wanted to see if there a jquery plugin that mimics this layout and functionality[image]

Comment: What browsers are you looking to support? This can easily be done using CSS alone.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is an **exact look-alike** http://jsfiddle.net/blackpla9ue/KHLgm/8/

A quick CSS only solution I managed to get done in a few minutes. Hover on the 2nd menu item for the dropdown.

Its pretty simple and straightforward and If you need any modifications added to that just let me know.

Comment: nice, it looks just like the one on amazon, but it's not a plugin.

Comment: glad you like it. its not a plugin but all you have to do is include the css portion and call the css class into ur `ul`

Answer (score 5):

There are maaaaany jQuery plugins that already do that, but here's a little plugin I've wrapped in 10 minutes :

```
(function($,window,undefined){
    var o;
    $.fn.amazonLikeMenu = function(data,options){
        o = $.extend({},options,$.fn.amazonLikeMenu.defaultOptions);
        return this.each(function(){
            createMenu($(this).addClass(o.classPrefix + '_container'),data);
        });
    };
    $.fn.amazonLikeMenu.defaultOptions = {
        classPrefix : "menu",
        eventPrefix : "menu"
    };
    function createMenu(container,data,options){

        container.data('initial_data',data);

        var ul = $('<ul />').addClass(o.classPrefix + '_ul').appendTo(container),
            liTemplate = $('<li />').addClass(o.classPrefix + '_li'),
            descTemplate = $('<span />').addClass(o.classPrefix + '_desc'),
            linkTemplate = $('<a href="#"/>').addClass(o.classPrefix + '_link'),
            hTemplate = $('<h3 />').addClass(o.classPrefix + '_link');

        $.each(data,function(i,el){
            var li = liTemplate.clone().appendTo(ul);
            if(el.title && el.link)
                if(typeof el.link === 'string')
                    linkTemplate 
                        .clone()
                        .text(el.title)
                        .attr('href',el.link)
                        .appendTo(li);

                else
                    {
                        createMenu(li.addClass(o.classPrefix + '_has_submenu').append(hTemplate.clone().text(el.title)),el.link,o);
                    }
             if(el.desc)
                descTemplate
                    .clone()
                    .text(el.desc)
                    .appendTo(li);
        });
    };
})(jQuery,window)
```

Your menu items consist of a collection of objects (useful if you generate the menu dynamically with data from a service) :

```
[
    {
        title : 'link 1',
        link : '#page1'
    },
    {
        title : 'link 2',
        link : '#page2',
        desc : 'this is an awesome link'
    },
    {
        title : 'link 3',
        link : [
            {
                title : "submenu link1",
                desc : "sample description",
                link : "#submenu_link_1"
            },
             {
                title : "submenu link2",
                link : "#submenu_link_2"
            },
             {
                title : "submenu link3",
                desc : "sample description",
                link : "#submenu_link_3"
            }
        ],
        desc : 'I have a submenu'
    },
    {
        title : 'link 3',
        link : '#page3',
        desc : 'I dont have a submenu :(('
    }
];
```

Here's a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/6QXZt/ .
It is customizable, so it can be adjusted to look exactly like the one on amazon.

P.S. : Must have in mind that the css role is greater than the jquery/javascript one in this case.

Answer (score 5):

Ben Kamen implemented a good one that works like the original. See the code at Github [here](https://github.com/kamens/jQuery-menu-aim). He wrote an [interesting post in his blog](http://bjk5.com/post/44698559168/breaking-down-amazons-mega-dropdown) about this topic.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slick one - http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-vertical-mega-menu-plugin/examples/.

Or for something simple - http://qrayg.com/experiment/cssmenus.

I don't think there are many basic (like amazon) vertical menu plugins with 'flyout' floating around cause they are fairly easy to create just with html/css alone.  The amazon menu could probably be done without any javascript at all.

Once you've built a nice css menu (bonus points for accessibility), you could easily convert a css hover action

e.g. `li:hover > ul {display:block}`

into some jquery

`$('li').hover(function(){ $(this).children('ul').show(200); })`.

Answer (score 1):

See this

http://speckyboy.com/2011/07/04/15-fresh-jquery-menu-plugins-and-tutorials/

Comment: which one in particular .. i don't see any on that page that match that functionality

Comment: Hi Leora, I have a solution of your requirement. How can i send you the code its too large i cant paste in the comments or in answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't listen to these clowns. You want one that is **tested** on many sites and **debugged** and is **cross-browser**. How many of these "look at me" menus handle **flash** or **select** elements behind the menu? How many have smooth **animation** and open-on-**hover** not onmouseover? How many can you easily **switch to horizontal** on another project without **learning even more css** class names and a new API?

Anyway, the answer is superfish:

http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#examples (vertical style)

Answer (score 0):

about what you want, I think you can create an drop down menu first and add the description later, just take a little look at this example, it is very basic:
http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-dropdown-menu
or here:
http://woork.blogspot.com/2008/01/simple-css-vertical-menu-digg-like.html

I have inspected element on amazon and I have found that they do the same way, they just add a class with a style for it:

```
<div class="navSaTagLine tiny">Vibrant color, movies, apps, and more</div>
```

Just make a drop down menu first and add the description you want!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these:

http://deluxe-menu.com/data-templates/amazon-template-sample.html
http://www.sothink.com/product/dhtmlmenu/samples/newamazonmenu/newamazonmenu.htm

Not sure if that's what you're for.