# Amazon Style Menu with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Does anyone know where I can find a jQuery Amazon style menu example?  I need to do something similar and I was hoping I wouldn't have to write it all myself.  Thanks!

Comment: [This should help](https://www.google.com/search?q=amazon+style+menu)

Comment: how 'bout this one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341853/is-there-any-jquery-plugin-that-mimics-the-amazon-com-menu-layout

Comment: It is named a "flyout menu", any Google search with this keyword and "css3" or "jquery" will give you lots of interesting results. If you're looking for exactly the same, it will be harder since their is done by a lot of background images (see that ressource of their website http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/08/gno/images/orangeBlue/navPackedSprites-FR-15._V202471902_.png)

Comment: not exactly the same, but maybe a good starting point http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/pro-flyout-list.html

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this, but the best thing write by your own

http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-vertical-mega-menu-plugin/examples/

http://qrayg.com/experiment/cssmenus/

http://speckyboy.com/2011/07/04/15-fresh-jquery-menu-plugins-and-tutorials/

http://apycom.com/

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/36-eye-catching-jquery-navigation-menus/